# Loading ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app. I have several views that rely on the same data. For that reason, in my controller, I thought I would create a shared function to populate the ViewBag. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
  await LoadViewBag();
  return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
  await LoadViewBag();
  return View();
}

private async Task<bool> LoadViewBag()
{
  ViewBag.PossibleTypes = await MyType.GetAllFromDatabase();
  ViewBag.PossibleContacts = await Contact.GetAllFromDatabase();
  ViewBag.InvitedBy = GetFullName();

  return true;
}
```

In my view, I then have:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.InvitedBy)
```

Unfortunately, the value put into InvitedBy is NEVER shown in the view. I set a breakpoint and it looks like its being set properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your breakpoint? Can you post your view?

Comment: What happens if you set the value for `ViewBag.InvitedBy` in the respective `ActionResult` instead of a shared function? Does it gets displayed on the view?

Comment: Ensure that you are using ASP.NET 4.5 and have `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to `4.5` in your `app.config`.

Comment: Could you also post the method "GetFullName()." You are applying the other properties like PossibleTypes and PossibleContacts from the response of a function. Are those showing up?

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve? Namely, what do you plan on doing with this data in your view? If `ViewBag` is the answer, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Dennis If I put ViewBag.InvitedBy in the ActionResult instead of the shared function, it DOES get displayed in the view.

Comment: @Gjohn - Nothing from the shared function is showing up in the view.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I want to display values from the ViewBag in my view. I want to load the view bag from a shared fucntion to reduce my code.

Comment: Isn't ViewBag only available to the controller to the view? I don't think you can set it like that and expect a value. You could try using TempData. That persists for an http session. More info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem).

Comment: @user687554: I surmised as much. My question is *how* will use be using the data? More likely than not, a child action would work just as well, while both removing code duplication *and* avoiding `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for the `ViewBag` only lives for the current request. You code does gets redirected to an `async Task` to set the values for the ViewBag. So the value you set for the `ViewBag` will die along with that request.

Rather if you set the values for the ViewBag in the respective ActionResult instead of a shared function then it will survive and you will get the value in the view.

You may consider using `TempData` instead. `TempData` internally uses the Session to store the value.

```
private async Task<bool> LoadViewBag()
{
  ...
  ...
  TempData["InvitedBy"] = GetFullName();

  return true;
}
```

Then in you view you can use

```
@if (TempData["InvitedBy"] != null)
{
   @Html.Raw(@TempData["Message"])
}
```

Comment: Is there a dynamic type I can use to bridge my controller and View? The problem with TempData is that as a dictionary, each element is an object. This pollutes my view as I end up having a bunch of Convert.ToString(TempData["SomeKey"]);

Comment: @user687554 I agree that ViewBag is a dynamic property and you don't need the type casting as it automatically derives the types from the respective object but you have to accept the drawbacks of ViewBag too. This is why you should use view models and strongly typed views instead of ViewBag/ViewData/TempData.

Answer (score 0):

Please assign the results of your calls to variables, then variables to ViewBags.