# ViewBag doesnt save state

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I testing my application, and while testing I catch one error which is I suppose came from ViewBage. 
I have list of 500 doctor and specilty, and when I want to edit phone, address etc. the dropdown show me SpeciltyName which is first in the list, so it doesnt  save the SpeciltyName of doctor
You can check picture below for beter understanding

[image]

[image]

**ContactController.cs**

```
// GET: Contacts/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = await db.Contacts.FindAsync(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.ContactTypes, "Id", "Name", contact.TypeId);
            ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.ContactCategories.Where(s => s.Name != "Attorney" && s.Name != "Law Firm"), "Id", "Name", contact.CategoryId);
            ViewBag.ConCompanyId = new SelectList(db.Contacts.Where(s => s.ContactCategory.Name == "Insurance Carrier" || s.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility"), "Id", "Firstname");
            return View(contact);
        }

        // POST: Contacts/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,UserId,Title,Firstname,Lastname,isCompany,CategoryId,TypeId,DateOfBirth,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zip,Email,Mobile,Phone,Website,Country,LocationGPS,Gender,Notes,Latitude,Longitude")] Contact contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }



            //ViewBag.Title = new SelectList(new[] { "Mr.", "Ms." }, contact.Title);
            ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.ContactTypes, "Id", "Name", contact.TypeId);
            ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.ContactCategories.Where(s => s.Name != "Attorney" && s.Name != "Law Firm"), "Id", "Name", contact.CategoryId);
            ViewBag.ConCompanyId = new SelectList(db.Contacts.Where(s => s.ContactCategory.Name == "Insurance Carrier" || s.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility"), "Id", "Firstname");
            return View(contact);
        }
```

Any help guys ?

Comment: If you at any points mentioning an error, please post the exact exception!

Comment: No, there is no error in console

Comment: Errors appear as exceptions in your code, not messages in the browser's console

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just mention that in my Visual Studio console output I don't get any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewBag value only lives for the current request. viewbag Code does gets redirected to an async Task to set the values for the ViewBag. So the value set for the ViewBag will die along with that request.
Solution:
Rather if you set the values for the ViewBag in the respective ActionResult instead of a shared function then it will survive and you will get the value in the view.

You may use TempData instead. TempData internally uses the Session to store the value.
[Please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125814/loading-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc)